# How to install JDK 1.4 on MAC

Tags: mac-osx, java, mac

```
I need install jdk 1.4 on mac os (Macintosh HD)
I tried downloading update packages but it gives following message
```

[image: Error]

Does anyone have any solution for this i need that jdk version for testing 1 application on my side

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User

Comment: What do you want with a more than 15 years old Java version? Note that usually for such an old software you should consider using an OS of a similar age (e.g. as virtual machine).